# Run click command from a given string

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I have a sample python script that uses the click library:

```py
import click

@click.group()
def cli(): 
    pass

@cli.command()
@click.argument("name", default="User")
def hello(name):
    print(f"Hello, {name}!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

I would like to run the command from a string so it can be called dynamically via code (with a loop over lines in a text file, for example). I have one solution using the `CliRunner` class, but it comes with the caveat:

> This only works in single-threaded systems without any concurrency as it changes the global interpreter state.

This solution looks like:

```py
import shlex
from click.testing import CliRunner

def run_line(line):
    runner = CliRunner()
    # Split with shlex to allow "quoted values"
    # Also use ternary to prevent empty arrays
    args = shlex.split(line) if line != "" else [""]
    # Get the function from globals, default to no subcommand
    command = globals().get(args.pop(0), cli)
    result = runner.invoke(command, args)

    print(result.output)

run_line("hello World")
```

The above outputs `Hello, World!`. I could probably use locks to guard against simultaneous access on files, but that still feels hacky given the note on the `CliRunner` class. Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong? Are you using the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) to create multiple threads? If not, there should be no worry.

Comment: @Bluenix Oh, so I should be able to use `multithreading` or something to create a handful of `CliRunner` objects that each have their own thread? The real commands would sometimes start threads as well, if they had to fetch multiple remote resources or had multiple long-running database queries. Would that use case function as expected?

Comment: There is no "`multithreading`" module, that's the `threading` module I mentioned above. Even then you are fine unless you are trying to make concurrent `runner.invoke()` calls. Like you mention yourself, in that case guard it with a global lock.

Comment: @Bluenix I was thinking of `multiprocessing`, but this is good information. Sounds like I may have been overly cautious. Thank you!

Comment: With multiprocessing you should be able have concurrent calls to `runner.invoke()` because the patching that happens does not affect other processes (since no memory is shared).